# QGIS exponential value to decimal value

Tags: gis, qgis

When I loaded my CSV data to QGIS, only some of the values are showing as decimals and some are showing as exponentials [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTiCD.jpg).
Why are only few cells showing data in exponential and rest are showing in normal way. I want to show all the decimal values on my map. How to change the exponential values to decimal.

((the decimal system is in German, so comma is point and point is comma) but all the qgis and csv are also working with german keyboard format. I haven,t faced issue for small decimal digits)

Only just one number in the whole row is showing in exponential,

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aBDatJijGaEpj3sHcFxIUHzWNSoP4mpJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you provide the original sample data (as shown in your screenshot)?

Comment: also: which QGIS-version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.14, pi version. I will upload it as soon as possible, because currently the data is being worked by other member.

Comment: I have shared the data, please look at it. I have tried today with qgis 3.10, still it showed ome values as exponential and some as normal decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that QGIS uses the exponential-notation automatically when a decimal number is less than 0.0001 (1e-4) **and** the corresponding field-type is `double`.

In order to use the data like you need, you have some options what to do:

- when you need the data for visualisation only, you could uncheck `Detect field types` at the "delimited text" import-dialog to force QGIS to import all fields as `string`. As in your original data all values are not in exponential notation you can visualise your data as expected.
- when you also need to do further calculations with your data prior to visualise it, the first option will not be suitable.

  - You could use the workaround shown in the following post to set the legend-precision: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307948/exponential-notation-in-attribute-table-qgis
  - You could also create a new field with the calculation results, which may be 10 or 100 times higher than the original value, so for visualisation no problem occurs.
- when you don't need to visualise your data and just wonder about the notation - don't worry, all calculations made with this value will be correct :-)

if all options are not suitable for you, let me know!

Comment: What u have told is correct. When the values are exceeding 5 digits after point, they are automatically showing as exponential values. 
- I have coverted the values to strings and then they are showing fine on the map. 

Thank you

Comment: if the answer helped you, please accept the answer (on the left side of it) ;-)